# Ember.js: Having problems creating a controller subclass

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a custom controller in Ember.js, and am having some trouble trying to make this work. Here is my app.js code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({   
  actions: {
    alert: function() {
      alert('yo');
    }
  }
});

App.LoginManagerView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'login/manager',
})

App.LoginManagerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['loginController'],
})


App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("root", {path: "/"});

  this.resource("login", function() {
    this.route("user");
    this.route("manager");
  })
});
```

And here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        {{#link-to 'root'}}Home{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to 'login.user'}}User{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to 'login.manager'}}Manager{{/link-to}}
      </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="root">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login/user">
    <h1>User</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login/manager">
    <h1>Manager</h1>
    <p>
      Name: {{controller}}
    </p>
    <button {{action controllers.loginController.alert}}>Alert</button>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.4.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I click User I can see the user view, but when I click manager I cant see the manager view. In fact, it seems its not even creating the Manager route. If I remove these lines:

```
App.LoginManagerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['loginController'],
})
```

it works, but I lose access to the login controller instance.

EDIT:

When I look at the Ember console and I cant see the routes, if I go back to js console I get this message:

> needs [ controller:loginController ] but it could not be found

How can I make it find the loginController instance?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ember, but couldn't you try something like App.LoginManagerController = App.LoginController.extend... ? I think  should LoginController should inherit that method

Comment: That would not achieve what I am trying to do. but thanks!

Comment: change needs to this: needs: ['login']